# Changing a <td> while selected, and reverting the changes after a different <td> is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am building a table and I want the background color of the selected cell to change. Then when i select a different cell (and apply the same change to this new cell), I want the change to revert in the first (no longer selected) cell. What is the best approach to this? Here is my code:

```
var table = '';

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    table += '<tr>';

    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        if (c == 0) {
            if (r == 0) {
                var cellID = r.toString();
                cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px;">' + '</td>';
            }
            else {
                var cellID = r.toString();
                cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px">' + r + '</td>';
            }
        }
        else if (r == 0 && c > 0) {
            var cellID = r.toString();
            cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
            table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px">' + letterArray[c - 1] + '</td>';
        }
        else {
            var cellID = r.toString();
            cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
            table += '<td id="' + cellID + '" style="min-width:50px; height:25px;" onclick="selectCell(this)">' + '</td>';
        }
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
```

Writing the table to the document:

```
document.write('<table id="table" border=1>' + table + '</table>');
```

selectCell function:

```
function selectCell(x) {
    alert("Row = " + x.parentNode.rowIndex + " Col = " + String.fromCharCode((x.cellIndex - 1) + 65));
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
}
```

This is where i encounter my problem. As I click the first cell, my alert shows me the info of which cell i have selected, and then changes the background color. Then when i select a different cell, it alerts me with the new cell row and column info, and changes the color.

What is the best way to revert the color change of the previously selected cell?

Thank you for your time and energy!

Comment: The best way would be to not use `document.write`. But in your case, it might work in a way when you are 1) unhighlighting _all_ cells, then 2) highlighting the _selected_ cell.

Comment: my question has been answered but thank you too for your time i appreciate it. can you elaborate (if only a little im sure your time is more valuable than just explaining stuff to me) on why i shouldn't use document.write?

Comment: `document.write()` overwrites the entire HTML page - you can essentially only use it once or you will always rewrite everything. You should really build the entire table and then use `document.body.appendChild(table)`. Similar to the CSS `classList` add/remove, you can use addChild and removeChild to add and remove elements from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a CSS class that applies the background color and add/remove it in your function. Your function can check for an element that already has the class, like this:

CSS:

```
.selected {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

JS:

```
function selectCell(x) {
  var currentSelection = document.querySelector('.selected');

  if (currentSelection) {
    currentSelection.classList.remove('selected');
  }

  x.classList.add('selected');
}
```

Comment: really cool idea. thank you. i'll try that. EDIT: yes thank you this is exactly waht i was hoping for. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Rishat Muhametshin that you should avoid using `document.write`. And I liked how @skyline3000 solved it so I put everything together into a snippet for you to see a cleaner way to code this.

I even went so far as to give you true headers on the top and the side and then added extra CSS to make them look more like headers.

```js
var rows = 7;
var cols = 8;
var table = document.createElement('table');
var selecedTd;
table.id = "table";
table.border = 1;
table.cellSpacing = 0;
table.cellPadding = 4;
document.body.appendChild(table);

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  if (r > 0) {
    tr.id = "row"+r;
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);

  for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    var cell;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(c+64);

    if (c===0 || r===0) {
      cell = document.createElement('th');
      cell.setAttribute('style', 'min-width:50px; height:25px;');
    } else {
      cell = document.createElement('td');
    }
    tr.appendChild(cell);
    

    if (c == 0 && r > 0) {
      cell.textContent = r;
    }
    else if (r == 0) {
      if (c > 0) {
        cell.textContent = char
        cell.id = "col"+c;
      }
    }
    else {
      cell.id = r+char;
      cell.addEventListener('click', selectCell);
      //cell.textContent = cell.id;
    }
  }
}


function selectCell(event) {
  var x = event.target;
  var currentSelection = document.querySelector('.selected');

  if (currentSelection) {
    currentSelection.classList.remove('selected');
  }

  x.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

th {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Below is code that will allow editing of the selected field. It needs work before it could be used in production and you would want to save the data in some array or object as well as in the cells, but it should get you going.

```js
var rows = 7;
var cols = 8;
var table = document.createElement('table');
var selecedTd;
var inputField = document.createElement('input');
table.id = "table";
table.border = 1;
table.cellSpacing = 0;
table.cellPadding = 4;
document.body.appendChild(table);
inputField.className = "roving-input";

for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  if (r > 0) {
    tr.id = "row"+r;
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);

  for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    var cell;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(c+64);

    if (c===0 || r===0) {
      cell = document.createElement('th');
    } else {
      cell = document.createElement('td');
    }
    tr.appendChild(cell);
    

    if (c == 0 && r > 0) {
      cell.textContent = r;
    }
    else if (r == 0) {
      if (c > 0) {
        cell.textContent = char
        cell.id = "col"+c;
      }
    }
    else {
      cell.id = r+char;
      cell.addEventListener('click', selectCell);
      cell.textContent = cell.id;
    }
  }
}


function selectCell(event) {
  var x = event.target;
  var currentSelection = document.querySelector('.selected');
  if (x !== currentSelection && x.localName === 'td') {
    if (currentSelection) {
      currentSelection.textContent = inputField.value;
      currentSelection.classList.remove('selected');
    }

    x.classList.add('selected');
    inputField.value = x.textContent;
    x.appendChild(inputField);
    inputField.style.width = (x.clientWidth-2)+'px';
    inputField.focus();
    inputField.select();
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  position: relative;
}

th {
  background-color: #DDD;
  height:25px;
  min-width:50px;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.roving-input {
  background-color: #FDF;
  border: none;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: this is awesome. thank you very much for your time and energy i really appreciate it

Comment: i have a further question which maybe you wouldn't mind explaining to me. Suppose i have a text field, and i want to enter the value in the text field into the selected cell. What would be the easiest way to interact with a particular cell? you modified my mechanic to apply an individual ID to each <td>, What is the best way for me to modify the cells individually? i'm trying it on my own here and i can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok. Review the updated code at the bottom of my answer.